# Can't conenct to any WiFi networks - "Can't Connect to This Network"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I'm having an issue.  When I try to connect to any wifi I always receive an error that says "can't connect to this network."  Even when I try to connect to other wifi networks, I get it, even if I type in an obviously incorrect password.  I can, however, connect when I'm plugging directly into the router.

I have tried the following:

- Forgetting a network and trying to connect again.
- Disabling and enabling wifi.
- Uninstalling the driver, restarting the PC.
- Disabling and enabling the wifi driver.

None have worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, it does still fail.  And it's not a specific network, it's ALL of the wifi networks within range.

Comment: Yeah I realized that just as I finished saving the comment, so I axed it. :)

Comment: Have you tried the latest driver offered by the WiFi adapter's manufacturer?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I have.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening due to a possible hardware error occurring in the Network Card or some error in the Config. in BIOS. You could probably try to 'Forget the Network' and connect to it again. It might also happen if you had MAC Address Filtering or some kind of connection restrictions set in your Router/Modem Settings.

Comment: There's definitely no MAC filtering, because I access the network when plugged in directly.  And I forgot the network already.